# How should I go from third activity to Main activity (First activity) without using finish()

Tags: android, android-activity

I am beginner in android development and i need to switch between activities without either destroying any activities during switching or using return button :).

I tried to go from third activity to the first one using the shown method but it was not working.

Please help with examples
Thanks in advance

First activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
 TextView developper_field = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.developper_field);
    developper_field.setText(R.string.developper_name);

    developped_by.setText(R.string.developped_by);
    Button start_app = (Button) findViewById(R.id.start_app);
    start_app.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,MainActivity2.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

}
}
```

Second Activity:

```
public class MainActivity2 extends Activity{

 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);
        final TextView info2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.info_id);
        info2.setText("This is second activity");
        Button Return = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Return_id);
        Return.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent intent = new  Intent(MainActivity2.this,MainActivity3.class);
                startActivity(intent);


            }
        });


    }
}
```

Third activity:

public class MainActivity3 extends Activity{

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main3);
    TextView message = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.message);
    message.setText("I am activity number 3");

    Button one = (Button) findViewById(R.id.one);
    one.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity3.this,MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });


}

}
```

Mainfest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.helloworld"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="16"
        android:targetSdkVersion="16" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/icon"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>


        <activity
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:name=".MainActivity2" >  
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:name=".MainActivity3" >
        </activity>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: switching means can you please clarify exact requirement?

Answer (score 0):

Try this, I think it might help you:

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
    startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to clear all stack then use flags for it when you call an intent from activity 3.

```
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
```

Answer (score 0):

As described on this answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/29731198/3922207

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, ActivityChild.class);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_TASK_ON_HOME);
startActivity(intent);
```

When you press the BACK button from child activity, those flags will bring you to MainActivity directly.

Answer (score 0):

Just use like this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
finish();
```

In the first parameter of Intent constructor it accepts a context. So you can pass `this` in an activity or pass `getActivity()` in a fragment.

If you use `finish()` after `startActivity()` it will not be started after back button is pressed.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use below flag :

```
Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK
```

Which are required `API level >= 11`

**Example :**

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity3.this,MainActivity.class);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK)
startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this to move to first activity from third,

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity3.this, MainActivity.class);
 intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
 startActivity(intent);
```